# Enter Button not acting like button click in MVC2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, button, enter

I have an MVC2 project that has a page on it that is supposed to call a jquery function.  When you click on the button via the mouse my jquery function is called.  I of course have a .click() function call on my button ID.  My guess is that I am simply performing a form submit when I press enter instead of going through the click motion.  Is there a way that I can either have the enter button do the same thing as the .click() or at least use jquery or anything as a matter of fact to disable the enter button so that a user can not hit enter and will have to press via the mouse?

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.  In the meantime, I will continue to scour the internet to figure out what I can do for this.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that you should be able to just hook into the forms [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
...
});
```

Using this should handle either the button click or an enter key press.

Comment: I would think so to.  But for some reason, It wasn't taking.

Comment: just took a look at my code again... I was attempting to use .submit on the button id and not the form ID?  Let me try on the form id and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#frmEdit").keypress(function (event) {

    if (event.which == 13 && event.target.nodeName != "TEXTAREA") {
        $('#btnSubmit').click();
        event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

This function looks for enter key press for all controls except TextArea and calls a submit event.